# APNS problems with special characters

Tags: php, iphone, apple-push-notifications

I have some problem with sending messages throw APNS, messages that contains special characters like É . What can be wrong? 
Please try this by yourself and if there is someone who knows the problem, please send me an answer. Thanks.
I have a php script to do this job

```
<?php

// Put your device token here (without spaces):
$deviceToken = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX';

// Put your private key's passphrase here:
$passphrase = 'XXXXXXXX';

// Put your alert message here:
$message = 'É';

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

$ctx = stream_context_create();
stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'local_cert', 'ck.pem');
stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'passphrase', $passphrase);

// Open a connection to the APNS server
$fp = stream_socket_client(
    'ssl://gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195', $err,
    $errstr, 60, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT|STREAM_CLIENT_PERSISTENT, $ctx);

if (!$fp)
    exit("Failed to connect: $err $errstr" . PHP_EOL);

echo 'Connected to APNS' . PHP_EOL;

// Create the payload body
$body['aps'] = array(
    'alert' => $message,
    'sound' => 'default'
    );

// Encode the payload as JSON
$payload = json_encode($body);

// Build the binary notification
$msg = chr(0) . pack('n', 32) . pack('H*', $deviceToken) . pack('n', strlen($payload)) . $payload;

// Send it to the server
$result = fwrite($fp, $msg, strlen($msg));

if (!$result)
    echo 'Message not delivered' . PHP_EOL;
else
    echo 'Message successfully delivered' . PHP_EOL;

// Close the connection to the server
fclose($fp);
```

What can be wrong with it?

Comment: worth a try: $message = utf8_encode($message);

Answer (score 0):

I know the question is old, but considering nobody replied, the problem was with the incoming data to my server, not the sending to the APNS, I solved it by putting a $message = urldecode($_REQUEST['message']);.